# optimize SVG layers for IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, svg

I'm trying to optimize a building colorizer application for IE8 and above and I'm having difficulties to display SVG layers within a div with a png background image in IE8+
I was trying to research here at SO and some other forums but could not find any similar issue with a solution. I hope someone can give an advice maybe a solution...
Here's the HTML part of my code :

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-7">
            <div class="building_area_eave_1" id="building_area">
                <svg class="svg_layers" version="1.0" id="full_x5F_wall_x5F_w_x5F_eave" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 664" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 664" xml:space="preserve">
                <polygon id="main_wall_1" fill="#f7f7f7" points="200.833,135.184 32.167,302.846 32.75,478 67.25,480 66.992,321.747 158,314.5 159,488 257.25,496.5 256.5,303.25 392.022,291.75 392.25,508 461,513 461,256 "/>
                <path id="main_wall_2" fill="#f7f7f7" d="M472.333,258.35V513L512,509.996L512.167,354l48.666,1.999l0.368,148.009l414.466-39L976,324.168  L472.333,258.35z M661.833,420L591,421v-59.834l70.833,2.667V420z"/>

            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS :

```
#building_area {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    background-clip: border-box;
    background-origin: padding-box;
    background-size:contain;
    background-position:center;
    position: relative;
}

.svg_layers {
    margin-top: 9px; 
    mix-blend-mode: multiply;
    opacity: 0.9;
}

.building_area_eave_1 {
    background: url("../images/1_part_eave_background.png") no-repeat;
}
```

The site looks good and works nice in FF and Safari, but the building_area div doesn't show up in IE8 and it is scaled down in IE9+
The `mix-blend-mode : multiply` filter doesn't work in Chrome 46.xxx but that's another issue... At this moment I'd like to optimize it for IE. Any help is highly appreciated.

The test site can be viewed [here](http://flexymanagement.com/buck_steel/steel_building/eave1).

Comment: Stack overflow is not really a place for asking for this kind of help.
I would look into the css rules you are using and searching for workarounds for older browser. Having IE8 support is a lot of work.

Comment: IE8 does not support SVG. IE9 is the earliest version of IE with SVG support.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. OK for IE8, I suppose I will have to ignore it. But why is my image shrinked in IE9+ instead of displaying it responsive?